# Streamgraphs in R?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, stream-graph

How can I implement Streamgraphs in R?

> Streamgraphs are a variant of stacked graphs and an improvement on
> Havre et al.'s ThemeRiver in the way the baseline is chosen, layer
> ordering, and color choice.

Example:

[image]

Reference: http://www.leebyron.com/else/streamgraph/

Comment: I believe the NYTimes example image you posted was initially created in R, like almost all of their graphics....

Comment: Here are a couple NYTimes links to [this chart](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/02/23/movies/20080223_REVENUE_GRAPHIC.html) and a [similar chart](http://www.nytimes.com/imagepages/2008/02/24/business/24METRIC_GRAPHIC.html)

Answer (score 43):

I wrote a function `plot.stacked` a while back that might be able to help you out.

The function is:

```
plot.stacked <- function(x,y, ylab="", xlab="", ncol=1, xlim=range(x, na.rm=T), ylim=c(0, 1.2*max(rowSums(y), na.rm=T)), border = NULL, col=rainbow(length(y[1,]))){

    plot(x,y[,1], ylab=ylab, xlab=xlab, ylim=ylim, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlim=xlim, t="n")
    bottom=0*y[,1]
    for(i in 1:length(y[1,])){
        top=rowSums(as.matrix(y[,1:i]))
        polygon(c(x, rev(x)), c(top, rev(bottom)), border=border, col=col[i])
        bottom=top
    }
    abline(h=seq(0,200000, 10000), lty=3, col="grey")
    legend("topleft", rev(colnames(y)), ncol=ncol, inset = 0, fill=rev(col), bty="0", bg="white", cex=0.8, col=col)
    box()
}
```

Here's an example data set and a plot:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- 500
n <- 15
x <- seq(m)
y <- matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=n)
colnames(y) <- seq(n)
for(i in seq(ncol(y))){
    mu <- runif(1, min=0.25*m, max=0.75*m)
    SD <- runif(1, min=5, max=30)
    TMP <- rnorm(1000, mean=mu, sd=SD)
    HIST <- hist(TMP, breaks=c(0,x), plot=FALSE)
    fit <- smooth.spline(HIST$counts ~ HIST$mids)
    y[,i] <- fit$y
}

    plot.stacked(x,y)
```

[image]

I can imagine that you would just need to adjust the definition of the polygon "bottom" to get the plot you desire.

### Update:

I've had another go at making the stream plot and believe I have more or less reproduced the idea in the function `plot.stream`, available [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/menugget/7864454) and also copied in at the bottom of this post. At [this link](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2013/12/data-mountains-and-streams-stacked-area.html) I show more detail of its use, but here's a basic example:

```
library(devtools)
source_url('https://gist.github.com/menugget/7864454/raw/f698da873766347d837865eecfa726cdf52a6c40/plot.stream.4.R')

set.seed(1)
m <- 500
n <- 50
x <- seq(m)
y <- matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=n)
colnames(y) <- seq(n)
for(i in seq(ncol(y))){
    mu <- runif(1, min=0.25*m, max=0.75*m)
    SD <- runif(1, min=5, max=30)
    TMP <- rnorm(1000, mean=mu, sd=SD)
    HIST <- hist(TMP, breaks=c(0,x), plot=FALSE)
    fit <- smooth.spline(HIST$counts ~ HIST$mids)
    y[,i] <- fit$y
}
y <- replace(y, y<0.01, 0)

#order by when 1st value occurs
ord <- order(apply(y, 2, function(r) min(which(r>0))))
y2 <- y[, ord]
COLS <- rainbow(ncol(y2))

png("stream.png", res=400, units="in", width=12, height=4)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), bty="n")
plot.stream(x,y2, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(100, 400), xaxs="i", center=TRUE, spar=0.2, frac.rand=0.1, col=COLS, border=1, lwd=0.1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

### Code for plot.stream()

```
#plot.stream makes a "stream plot" where each y series is plotted 
#as stacked filled polygons on alternating sides of a baseline.
#
#Arguments include:
#'x' - a vector of values
#'y' - a matrix of data series (columns) corresponding to x
#'order.method' = c("as.is", "max", "first") 
#  "as.is" - plot in order of y column
#  "max" - plot in order of when each y series reaches maximum value
#  "first" - plot in order of when each y series first value > 0
#'center' - if TRUE, the stacked polygons will be centered so that the middle,
#i.e. baseline ("g0"), of the stream is approximately equal to zero. 
#Centering is done before the addition of random wiggle to the baseline. 
#'frac.rand' - fraction of the overall data "stream" range used to define the range of
#random wiggle (uniform distrubution) to be added to the baseline 'g0'
#'spar' - setting for smooth.spline function to make a smoothed version of baseline "g0"
#'col' - fill colors for polygons corresponding to y columns (will recycle)
#'border' - border colors for polygons corresponding to y columns (will recycle) (see ?polygon for details)
#'lwd' - border line width for polygons corresponding to y columns (will recycle)
#'...' - other plot arguments
plot.stream <- function(
    x, y, 
    order.method = "as.is", frac.rand=0.1, spar=0.2,
    center=TRUE,
    ylab="", xlab="",  
    border = NULL, lwd=1, 
    col=rainbow(length(y[1,])),
    ylim=NULL, 
    ...
){

if(sum(y < 0) > 0) error("y cannot contain negative numbers")

if(is.null(border)) border <- par("fg")
border <- as.vector(matrix(border, nrow=ncol(y), ncol=1))
col <- as.vector(matrix(col, nrow=ncol(y), ncol=1))
lwd <- as.vector(matrix(lwd, nrow=ncol(y), ncol=1))

if(order.method == "max") {
    ord <- order(apply(y, 2, which.max))
    y <- y[, ord]
    col <- col[ord]
    border <- border[ord]
}

if(order.method == "first") {
    ord <- order(apply(y, 2, function(x) min(which(r>0))))
    y <- y[, ord]
    col <- col[ord]
    border <- border[ord]
}

bottom.old <- rep(0, length(x))
top.old <- rep(0, length(x))
polys <- vector(mode="list", ncol(y))
for(i in seq(polys)){
    if(i %% 2 == 1){ #if odd
        top.new <- top.old + y[,i]
        polys[[i]] <- list(x=c(x, rev(x)), y=c(top.old, rev(top.new)))
        top.old <- top.new
    }
    if(i %% 2 == 0){ #if even
        bottom.new <- bottom.old - y[,i]
        polys[[i]] <- list(x=c(x, rev(x)), y=c(bottom.old, rev(bottom.new)))
        bottom.old <- bottom.new
    }
}

ylim.tmp <- range(sapply(polys, function(x) range(x$y, na.rm=TRUE)), na.rm=TRUE)
outer.lims <- sapply(polys, function(r) rev(r$y[(length(r$y)/2+1):length(r$y)]))
mid <- apply(outer.lims, 1, function(r) mean(c(max(r, na.rm=TRUE), min(r, na.rm=TRUE)), na.rm=TRUE))

#center and wiggle
if(center) {
    g0 <- -mid + runif(length(x), min=frac.rand*ylim.tmp[1], max=frac.rand*ylim.tmp[2])
} else {
    g0 <- runif(length(x), min=frac.rand*ylim.tmp[1], max=frac.rand*ylim.tmp[2])
}

fit <- smooth.spline(g0 ~ x, spar=spar)

for(i in seq(polys)){
    polys[[i]]$y <- polys[[i]]$y + c(fitted(fit), rev(fitted(fit)))
}

if(is.null(ylim)) ylim <- range(sapply(polys, function(x) range(x$y, na.rm=TRUE)), na.rm=TRUE)
plot(x,y[,1], ylab=ylab, xlab=xlab, ylim=ylim, t="n", ...)
for(i in seq(polys)){
    polygon(polys[[i]], border=border[i], col=col[i], lwd=lwd[i])
}

}
```

Comment: By the way, it does not appear that the colors indicate "strength" but are rather identifiers for a specific variable

Comment: @Dualinity - No, in this example, colors are based on when each data series fist appears on the x axis. The link provides another example where colors are by the maximum attained in the series (similar to the NY Times example shown in the question).

Comment: @Marcinthebox Mind if I copy over the code from the linked gist so that it will persist here even if the gist goes away some day? I'd copy it in below the currently final figure so that it doesn't hurt the rest of the post's flow.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - Very good - go ahead and copy it over. Thanks for bringing attention to this with you bounty as well.

Comment: @Marcinthebox -- Thanks, done. I was delighted to see this question pop back up with not just one but two new answers, and thought others might enjoy seeing them as well.

Comment: @Marcinthebox +1 this is awesome. You might want to look at `RColorBrewer` (if you haven't already heard of it) to pick more natural colour palettes than `rainbow`.

Comment: @SimonO101 - Cheers. Yes, I just quickly used the existing rainbow palette to demonstrate the concept. At [my blog](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2013/12/data-mountains-and-streams-stacked-area.html), I show the function's use with some other palettes.

Comment: @SimonO101 - ah yes, now I remember the advantages of the ready-made color palettes in `RColorBrewer` - i.e. based on color theory. I'll check it out again. Cheers

Comment: @Marcinthebox no probs. Really great graphics and I checked out your blog post too. Nice.

Answer (score 10):

These days there's a streamgraphs htmlwidget:

https://hrbrmstr.github.io/streamgraph/

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/streamgraph")

library(streamgraph)

streamgraph(data, key, value, date, width = NULL, height = NULL,
  offset = "silhouette", interpolate = "cardinal", interactive = TRUE,
  scale = "date", top = 20, right = 40, bottom = 30, left = 50)
```

It produces really pretty charts and is even interactive.
[image]

**Edit**

Another option is to use [ggTimeSeries](https://github.com/AtherEnergy/ggTimeSeries) which uses the syntax of ggplot2:

```
# creating some data
library(ggTimeSeries)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)
dfData = data.frame(
   Time = 1:1000,
   Signal = abs(
      c(
         cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 3)), 
         cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 4)), 
         cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 1)),
         cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 2))
      )
   ),
   VariableLabel = c(rep('Class A', 1000),
                     rep('Class B', 1000),
                     rep('Class C', 1000),
                     rep('Class D', 1000))
)

# base plot
ggplot(dfData,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Signal,
           group = VariableLabel,
           fill = VariableLabel)) +
   stat_steamgraph() +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the plot is produce on an html page, not on an R device

Comment: The question didn't specify that the plots can't be in html. Plus you can create interactive visualisations in html reports using RMarkdown.

Comment: I did not mean to criticize the answer (therefore my upvote). I only meant to point out the output is not an R object.

Comment: I don't share HelloWorld's view that it's "not an R object" - it seems to me it's just an unusual R object made of HTML! But the fact is I can't seem how to script the output a PDF/PNG of the plot. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Comment: No idea. I've never tried doing it. It might be worth asking a separate question.

Answer (score 9):

Adding one line to Marc in the box's nifty code will get you much closer. (Getting the rest of the way will just be a matter of setting fill colors based on the max height of each curve.)

```
## reorder the columns so each curve first appears behind previous curves
## when it first becomes the tallest curve on the landscape
y <- y[, unique(apply(y, 1, which.max))]

## Use plot.stacked() from Marc's post
plot.stacked(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice addition! This stream function is more complicated than I originally thought. From the documentation (www.leebyron.com/else/streamgraph/download.php?file=stackedgraphs_byron_wattenberg.pdf) it looks like there is an underlying meandering baseline (g0), with the histograms stacked alternately on top or bottom of g0. Still, it should be relatively easy to adapt the function to do this. I haven't read the details, but one tricky part may be how to define an appropriate degree of (random?) meandering on g0.

Comment: @Marcinthebox -- Thanks for spurring me to actually go look at that article. Very interesting! Also, I agree that getting a meandering midline (and then all of the peaks correct relative to it) would be the tricky part.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a solution using `lattice::xyplot`. The code is at my
[spacetimeVis repository](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/spacetime-vis/blob/master/timeHorizontalAxis.R#L297).

The next example use this [data set](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/spacetime-vis/blob/master/data/unemployUSA.RData?raw=true):

```
library(lattice)
library(zoo)
library(colorspace)

nCols <- ncol(unemployUSA)
pal <- rainbow_hcl(nCols, c=70, l=75, start=30, end=300)
myTheme <- custom.theme(fill=pal, lwd=0.2)

xyplot(unemployUSA, superpose=TRUE, auto.key=FALSE,
       panel=panel.flow, prepanel=prepanel.flow,
       origin='themeRiver', scales=list(y=list(draw=FALSE)),
       par.settings=myTheme)
```

It produces this image.

[image: themeRiver]

`xyplot` needs two functions to work: `panel.flow` and `prepanel.flow`:

```
panel.flow <- function(x, y, groups, origin, ...){
  dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, groups=groups)
  nVars <- nlevels(groups)
  groupLevels <- levels(groups)

  ## From long to wide
  yWide <- unstack(dat, y~groups)
  ## Where are the maxima of each variable located? We will use
  ## them to position labels.
  idxMaxes <- apply(yWide, 2, which.max)

  ##Origin calculated following Havr.eHetzler.ea2002
  if (origin=='themeRiver') origin= -1/2*rowSums(yWide)
  else origin=0 
  yWide <- cbind(origin=origin, yWide)
  ## Cumulative sums to define the polygon
  yCumSum <- t(apply(yWide, 1, cumsum))
  Y <- as.data.frame(sapply(seq_len(nVars),
                            function(iCol)c(yCumSum[,iCol+1],
                                            rev(yCumSum[,iCol]))))
  names(Y) <- levels(groups)
  ## Back to long format, since xyplot works that way
  y <- stack(Y)$values

  ## Similar but easier for x
  xWide <- unstack(dat, x~groups)
  x <- rep(c(xWide[,1], rev(xWide[,1])), nVars)
  ## Groups repeated twice (upper and lower limits of the polygon)
  groups <- rep(groups, each=2)

  ## Graphical parameters
  superpose.polygon <- trellis.par.get("superpose.polygon")
  col = superpose.polygon$col
  border = superpose.polygon$border 
  lwd = superpose.polygon$lwd 

  ## Draw polygons
  for (i in seq_len(nVars)){
    xi <- x[groups==groupLevels[i]]
    yi <- y[groups==groupLevels[i]]
    panel.polygon(xi, yi, border=border,
                  lwd=lwd, col=col[i])
  }

  ## Print labels
  for (i in seq_len(nVars)){
    xi <- x[groups==groupLevels[i]]
    yi <- y[groups==groupLevels[i]]
    N <- length(xi)/2
    ## Height available for the label
    h <- unit(yi[idxMaxes[i]], 'native') -
      unit(yi[idxMaxes[i] + 2*(N-idxMaxes[i]) +1], 'native')
    ##...converted to "char" units
    hChar <- convertHeight(h, 'char', TRUE)
    ## If there is enough space and we are not at the first or
    ## last variable, then the label is printed inside the polygon.
    if((hChar >= 1) && !(i %in% c(1, nVars))){
      grid.text(groupLevels[i],
                xi[idxMaxes[i]],
                (yi[idxMaxes[i]] +
                 yi[idxMaxes[i] + 2*(N-idxMaxes[i]) +1])/2,
                gp = gpar(col='white', alpha=0.7, cex=0.7),
                default.units='native')
    } else {
      ## Elsewhere, the label is printed outside

      grid.text(groupLevels[i],
                xi[N],
                (yi[N] + yi[N+1])/2,
                gp=gpar(col=col[i], cex=0.7),
                just='left', default.units='native')
    }
  }
}

prepanel.flow <- function(x, y, groups, origin,...){
  dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, groups=groups)
  nVars <- nlevels(groups)
  groupLevels <- levels(groups)
  yWide <- unstack(dat, y~groups)
  if (origin=='themeRiver') origin= -1/2*rowSums(yWide)
  else origin=0
  yWide <- cbind(origin=origin, yWide)
  yCumSum <- t(apply(yWide, 1, cumsum))

  list(xlim=range(x),
       ylim=c(min(yCumSum[,1]), max(yCumSum[,nVars+1])),
       dx=diff(x),
       dy=diff(c(yCumSum[,-1])))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this with `ggplot2`. I'm going to edit it later and will also upload the csv data somewhere sensible.

Couple of issues I need to think about:

1. Getting the y value from the smoothed graph so you can overplot the name for high grossing movies
2. Adding a 'wave' to the x-axis as per your example.

Both should be OK to do with a bit of thought. Sadly the interactivity will be tricky. Maybe will have a look at `googleVis`.

[image]

```
## PRE-REQS
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)

## GET SOME BASIC DATA
films<-read.csv("box.csv")

## ALL OF THIS IS FAKING DATA
get_dist<-function(n,g){

  dist<-g-(abs(sort(g-abs(rnorm(n,g,g*runif(1))))))
  dist<-c(0,dist-min(dist),0)
  dist<-dist*g/sum(dist)
  return(dist)
}

get_dates<-function(w){
  start<-as.Date("01-01-00",format="%d-%m-%y")+ceiling(runif(1)*365)
  return(start+w)
}

films$WEEKS<-ceiling(runif(1)*10)+6
f<-ddply(films,.(RANK),function(df)expand.grid(RANK=df$RANK,WEEKGROSS=get_dist(df$WEEKS,df$GROSS)))
weekly<-merge(films,f,by=("RANK"))


## GENERATE THE PLOT DATA
plot.data<-ddply(weekly,.(RANK),summarise,NAME=NAME,WEEKDATE=get_dates(seq_along(WEEKS)*7),WEEKGROSS=ifelse(RANK %% 2 == 0,-WEEKGROSS,WEEKGROSS),GROSS=GROSS)

g<-ggplot() + 

  geom_area(data=plot.data[plot.data$WEEKGROSS>=0,],
            aes(x=WEEKDATE,
                ymin=0,
                y=WEEKGROSS,
                group=NAME,
                fill=cut(GROSS,c(seq(0,1000,100),Inf)))
            ,alpha=0.5,
            stat="smooth", fullrange=T,n=1000,
            colour="white",
            size=0.25,alpha=0.5) +

  geom_area(data=plot.data[plot.data$WEEKGROSS<0,],
            aes(x=WEEKDATE,
                ymin=0,
                y=WEEKGROSS,
                group=NAME,
                fill=cut(GROSS,c(seq(0,1000,100),Inf)))
            ,alpha=0.5,
            stat="smooth", fullrange=T,n=1000,
            colour="white",
            size=0.25,alpha=0.5) +

  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdPu",name="Gross\nEUR (M)") +
  ylab("") + xlab("")

b<-ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]
b.ymax<-max(b$y)


## MAKE LABELS FOR GROSS > 450M
labels<-ddply(plot.data[plot.data$GROSS>450,],.(RANK,NAME),summarise,x=median(WEEKDATE),y=ifelse(sum(WEEKGROSS)>0,b.ymax,-b.ymax),GROSS=max(GROSS))
labels<-ddply(labels,.(y>0),transform,NAME=paste(NAME,GROSS),y=(y*1.1)+((seq_along(y)*20*(y/abs(y)))))

## PLOT
g + 
  geom_segment(data=labels,aes(x=x,xend=x,y=0,yend=y,label=NAME),size=0.5,linetype=2,color="purple",alpha=0.5) +
  geom_text(data=labels,aes(x,y,label=NAME),size=3)
```

Here's a `dput()` of the films df if anyone wants to play with it:

```
structure(list(RANK = 1:50, NAME = structure(c(2L, 45L, 18L, 
                                               33L, 32L, 29L, 34L, 23L, 4L, 21L, 38L, 46L, 15L, 36L, 26L, 49L, 
                                               16L, 8L, 5L, 31L, 17L, 27L, 41L, 3L, 48L, 40L, 28L, 1L, 6L, 24L, 
                                               47L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 39L, 14L, 30L, 20L, 22L, 11L, 19L, 25L, 35L, 
                                               9L, 43L, 44L, 37L, 7L, 42L, 50L), .Label = c("Alice in Wonderland", 
                                                                                            "Avatar", "Despicable Me 2", "E.T.", "Finding Nemo", "Forrest Gump", 
                                                                                            "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2", 
                                                                                            "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince", "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 
                                                                                            "Independence Day", "Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull", 
                                                                                            "Iron Man", "Iron Man 2", "Iron Man 3", "Jurassic Park", "LOTR: The Return of the King", 
                                                                                            "Marvel's The Avengers", "Pirates of the Caribbean", "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End", 
                                                                                            "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest", "Return of the Jedi", 
                                                                                            "Shrek 2", "Shrek the Third", "Skyfall", "Spider-Man", "Spider-Man 2", 
                                                                                            "Spider-Man 3", "Star Wars", "Star Wars: Episode II -- Attack of the Clones", 
                                                                                            "Star Wars: Episode III", "Star Wars: The Phantom Menace", "The Dark Knight", 
                                                                                            "The Dark Knight Rises", "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey", 
                                                                                            "The Hunger Games", "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire", "The Lion King", 
                                                                                            "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", 
                                                                                            "The Passion of the Christ", "The Sixth Sense", "The Twilight Saga: Eclipse", 
                                                                                            "The Twilight Saga: New Moon", "Titanic", "Toy Story 3", "Transformers", 
                                                                                            "Transformers: Dark of the Moon", "Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen", 
                                                                                            "Up"), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2009L, 1997L, 2012L, 2008L, 
                                                                                                                               1999L, 1977L, 2012L, 2004L, 1982L, 2006L, 1994L, 2010L, 2013L, 
                                                                                                                               2012L, 2002L, 2009L, 1993L, 2011L, 2003L, 2005L, 2003L, 2004L, 
                                                                                                                               2004L, 2013L, 2011L, 2002L, 2007L, 2010L, 1994L, 2007L, 2007L, 
                                                                                                                               2008L, 2001L, 2008L, 2001L, 2010L, 2002L, 2007L, 1983L, 1996L, 
                                                                                                                               2003L, 2012L, 2012L, 2009L, 2010L, 2009L, 2013L, 2010L, 1999L, 
                                                                                                                               2009L), GROSS = c(760.5, 658.6, 623.4, 533.3, 474.5, 460.9, 448.1, 
                                                                                                                                                 436.5, 434.9, 423.3, 422.7, 415, 409, 408, 403.7, 402.1, 395.8, 
                                                                                                                                                 381, 380.8, 380.2, 377, 373.4, 370.3, 366.9, 352.4, 340.5, 336.5, 
                                                                                                                                                 334.2, 329.7, 321, 319.1, 318.3, 317.6, 317, 313.8, 312.1, 310.7, 
                                                                                                                                                 309.4, 309.1, 306.1, 305.4, 304.4, 303, 301.9, 300.5, 296.6, 
                                                                                                                                                 296.3, 295, 293.5, 293), WEEKS = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), .Names = c("RANK", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "NAME", "YEAR", "GROSS", "WEEKS"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```