# R plot like the "the ebb and flow of movies -- nytimes"

Tags: r, plot, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Streamgraphs in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084998/streamgraphs-in-r)

I would like to produce a plot like this in R:
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/02/23/movies/20080223_REVENUE_GRAPHIC.html

But instead of movies, I would like to see the evolution of tag usage from the stackexchange site superuser.com over time. I don't mind not being able to interactively click on the different parts of the graphics, a static plot with R will do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not done with R -- have a look at [d3](http://www.d3js.org), a Javascript library.  The NY Times even hired its author, [Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/).

There are also a number of presentations by the NYT Graphics team floating around, see e.g. [the Revolutions Blog entry](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/03/how-the-new-york-times-uses-r-for-data-visualization.html).

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind not being able to interactively click on the different parts of the graphics, a static plot with R will do. Edited question now.